# Sending mouse position with jquery $.ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send mouse position to server with jquery  $.ajax method  but i can't make it right.

```
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        var x = e.pageX;
        var y = e.pageY;
        $(document).mousemove(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "get_position.php",
                data: {
                    pos_x: x,
                    pos_y: y
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

this code crashes the browser .What is the right way to do this ?

Comment: You are sending an AJAX request on *every* mouse move. Thats gotta crash *any* browser.

Comment: It might be you are sending so much requests the browser just can't catch up. Mousemove is pretty **frequent** event. Try collecting the mouse positions into an array and than periodically send the ajax updates. P.S. great DoS attack on browser, and pretty legal, thanks :)

Comment: check out this link here http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position

Answer (score 4):

You are sending an AJAX request on *every* mouse move. Thats gotta crash any browser.

Instead, store the mouse coords on some variable on every mouse move but dont send them to the server every time. Send them to the server periodically, say once every minute or so.

i.e. Something like:

```
var coords = [0, 0];
$(document).mousemove(function (e) {
   coords = [e.pageX, e.pageY];
});

function sendThem() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "get_position.php",
        data: {
            pos_x: coords[0],
            pos_y: coords[1]
        }
    });
}

setInterval(sendThem, 1000);
```

Comment: I'd use a coords object `var coords = {}` and set or get coords.x/coords.y.

Comment: should be `var coords = [0, 0]`

Comment: @London-35 no clue how i managed to not notice such an elementary mistake! Thanks for pointing out. Fixed. (btw, I answered this almost 10 years ago!)